# How to combine cypher queries into a transaction in Py2neo v3

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

In py2neo v2.0, it was possible to use a transaction to execute Cypher statements:

```
tx=graph.cypher.begin()
tx.append("MERGE (n:Process {proc_nm : {proc_nm}}) ON CREATE SET n.count = 1 ON MATCH SET n.count = n.count +1", {proc_nm : 'wibble'})
tx.commit
```

When processing complex files this allows very fast updates to be made to the Neo4J database.

In py2neo v3.0 the syntax has changed to:

```
graph.run(("MERGE (n:Process {proc_nm : {proc_nm}}) ON CREATE SET n.count = 1 ON MATCH SET n.count = n.count +1", {proc_nm : 'wibble'}))
```

This means that I can run the cypher statements singly but the performance takes a massive hit.  I can write CREATE/MERGE for the Nodes and Relationships however I was hoping to not have to re-write a bunch of routines that I'm already using.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In py2neo v3, you can still use a [Transaction](http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.Transaction), but the API has changed a bit.

In your sample code, you must now:

- Use `graph.begin` instead of  `graph.cypher.begin`.
- Use `tx.run` instead of  `tx.append`.

This pattern should work in v3:

```
tx=graph.begin()
tx.run(" ... Cypher statement 1 ... ", { ... })
tx.run(" ... Cypher statement 2 ... ", { ... })
tx.run(" ... Cypher statement 3 ... ", { ... })
tx.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Greatly appreciated.