# AttributeError: 'Transaction' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

Well, I started to work with Py2neo and Neo4j in order to initiate a connection between them and already installed both libraries correctly without no errors. When I decide to start training by the following commands:

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph("bolt://localhost:7687", user="neo4j", password="mypass")
tx = graph.begin()
for name in ["Mohammad", "Ahmad", "Dad", "Mom"]:
    tx.append("CREATE (person:Person {name:{name}}) RETURN person", name=name)
Mohammad, Ahmad, Dad, Mom = [result.one for result in tx.commit()]
```

a errors show up:

```
> AttributeError: 'Transaction' object has no attribute 'append'
```

is there any solution to eliminate the error, does append attribute expired in py2neo and replaced by a new one?

Comment: https://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#transactions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine cypher queries into a transaction in Py2neo v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199114/how-to-combine-cypher-queries-into-a-transaction-in-py2neo-v3)

Answer (score 2):

try using run method:

```
tx = graph.begin()
tx.run("CREATE (person:Person {name:{name}}) RETURN person", name=name) 
tx.commit()
```

Comment: gives syntax error. on old {name} param style, must use $name now

Answer (score 1):

don't use append.
firstly you need to create a node, this you can achieve by :-

```
tx = graph.begin()
a = Node("linkedinn",name="random")
tx.create(a) 
tx.commit()
```

this way you can create a node in the graph. For now i don't really know why append does not work.I too had the same problem.